# Pythonic syntax to concatenate the keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary similar to this one

```
dic1 = {'Name': 'John', 'Time': 'morning'}
```

I want to concatenante the keys and values with a "_" separator with the following schema:

```
Name_John_Time_morning
```

This is equivalent to key1_value1_key2_value2

I have tried the following line of code but without success

```
x + "_" + v for x,v in dict1.keys(), dict1.values()
```

Comment: I'd throw in a caveat and say that *you are not in general guaranteed of the order of dictionary keys*. It works out in this case but you should be using `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like comprehensions better

```
result = '_'.join(x + '_' + y for x, y in dic1.items())
```

or

```
result = '_'.join('{}_{}'.format(*p) for p in dic1.items())
```

The latter form also works when there are non-string keys or values.

To ensure the output is sorted,

```
result = '_'.join('{}_{}'.format(*p) for p in sorted(dic1.items()))
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I would like to know how the *p works in the statement result = '_'.join('{}_{}'.format(*p) for p in dic1.items())

Answer (score 5):

Using [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> dic1 = {'Name': 'John', 'Time': 'morning'}
>>> '_'.join(map('_'.join, dic1.items()))
'Name_John_Time_morning'
```

or using generator expression instead of `map`:

```
>>> '_'.join('_'.join(item) for item in dic1.items())
'Name_John_Time_morning'
```

BTW, `dict` is not ordered. So result may vary.

Comment: I feel like ['_'.join(item) for item in dic1.items] is more Pythonic. But that is just my opinion.

Comment: @icedtrees, Thank you for comment. I added a generator expression version.

Answer (score 2):

```
 print "_".join("{}_{}".format(k,v) for k,v in dic1.items())
```

*Gives:*

```
Name_John_Time_morning
```

Answer (score 0):

If we're golfing and I've got itertools...

```
'_'.join(chain(*dic1.items()))
```